# Bluemix にて PostgreSQL by Compose サービスが作成できない

Tags: bluemix

Compose アカウントを取得し、PostgreSQL データベースを作成した後、Bluemix の Web コンソールから PostgreSQL by Compose のサービスを作成しようとしていますが、作成できません。

作成が成功した方がいらっしゃれば、以下の作成方法についてコメントをいただけますでしょうか。

1. 右下の「Username」、「Password」、「Public hostname/Port」に値を入力します。
   　「Username」と「Password」には、Compose アカウントと作成した DB のアカウントの両方を試しました。
2. 「作成」ボタンを押します。
   　ボタンは押せはしますが、その後画面が遷移するわけでもなく、サービスが作成される様子はありません。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Composeに登録して、同様にUsername/Pass/Host/Portを入力して、BlumiexからPostgreのServiceを作成しようとしましたが、"This value is required"と入力チェックが通らず、作成できませんでした。

Issue Ticket を上げてみましたので、返答が来たらお伝えしますね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現在問題対応中とのことでした。

また、BluemixでCompose PostgresqlのServiceを追加しアプリに組み込むのと、Compose.ioのDB作成時に割り振られるCredential情報を使ってBluemixアプリからCompose Postgresqlに接続するのとで、仕組みもコスト面も現状では差異が無いので、さしあたり後者の方法でアプリケーションに組み込むようにしてくださいとのことでした。

Comment: 情報のご提供、ありがとうございます！
現在作成しているアプリでは、VCAP_SERVICES から接続情報を取得するようにしていますので、とりあえずは自前で VCAP_SERVICES に情報を仕込むことで対応しようと思います。